# Trying to get a sum between years

Tags: sql

Hello I am trying to get a sum between two different dates but the code is not working....what am I doing wrong

```
select 
id_number,
sum (CREDIT_AMOUNT) 
from GIFTDET 
where FY between '2015' and '2012' 
group by ID_NUMBER
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Between is the culprit here. There is NOTHING between 2015 and 2012. You should consider not using between because it causes lots of other issues. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 0):

It is "not working" probably because 2015 is more than 2012